# Angualr2 RC4 child component property setter not executed

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component that includes a child components which displayes a array of places in a map. The places to display are loaded in the parent component. I have this in my parent template:

```
<map-comp class="container-map" [places]="places"></map-comp>
```

I load my places in this whay:

```
myservice.myfunction(myparameters).subscribe((res: Array<Place>) => {
                        this.places = res
                    });
```

In my child component i have this property:

```
  @Input() set places(places: Array<Place>) {
    this._places = places;
    if (this._places != null) {
        this.placesChanged();
    }
}
```

If I load my parent component the set places property is fired with places equal undefined. Then starts myfunction that loads data and sets the property in the parent component but the child parents property is not update.
What I do wrong?

**UPDATE**
Here is my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/MROuH8znbDxTm0HKFG0Q

If I use the self.mapConfigChanged.emit(); outside of the google maps event listner it works. But I need some data from the map so I must use this event

Comment: Could you show the template of the child component? If you set the `places` array in the constructor of the parent component, the child component shows the elements correctly?

Comment: in the child component template isn't nothing about the places array. the placesChanged event in the childs loads some marker in the google map of the child component

Comment: no putting the load places code in the constructor doesn't change. the data are loaded after executing a click on a button the shows and hides a element in the parent component

Comment: Check the plunker and try to reproduce your issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/LxAcuEEYjjHVVETdVqNJ?p=preview

Comment: ok i will try to reproduce my problem on plunker. i hope that is not a problem with the combination with google maps.

Comment: @AlexandreJunges take a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/MROuH8znbDxTm0HKFG0Q if I put the emit not in the google map event listener it works. but i must wait until the map is loaded to have all the data to load my places

Comment: @AlexandreJunges see the solution below. works thx for your help

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend [@juristr](http://twitter.com/juristr) solved my issue. Many thanks!
The problem is solved by using ngZone when updating the places in the parent control.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cUG1aqhQhnniD9D87rAa

```
 private mapConfigChange() {

    this.zone.run(() => {
      console.log("parent event fired");
      this.loadPlaces();  
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just modify the array (add/remove) passed previously using `[places]="places"` then the `set places(...)` won't be called for such changes.
Angular doesn't compare array content and object properties, it only compares object identity.
You can try executing `this.places = this.places.slice();` after the array was changed to cause Angular2 change detection to update the binding.
If this fixes your issue you could use observeables to notify about updates which also emit events when the value didn't actually change.

Comment: no the slice() doesn't change my problem. i will try to create a plunker starting by the example of alexandre